# Why can't I move a file into the windows system32 folder from a UEFI shell

Tags: windows-7, uefi

It gives me some sort of error along the lines of "this folder is read only"

Comment: System32 is on System drive that's formatted as NTFS file system. As of now your UEFI is  not equipped to handle NTFS file system in read/write mode. It can only read NTFS but not write to it. Hence you get read only message.

Comment: @patkim.  Since when did UEFI firmware have native read-only NTFS support?

Comment: @fpmurphy Any that implement a driver for it.

Comment: @jdwolf  Know any UEFI vendor that provides NTFS support OOTB?

Comment: well my MSI z370 gaming plus has "boot into UEFI shell" and lets me browse my NTFS filesystem, so if that qualifies then I guess that motherboard?

Comment: @patkim but I can copy to other folders, it's just some folders that won't let me, like a permissions error but I didn't think that permissions were specific to the hardware, I thought they were specific to the operating system